# How to correctly implement this layout using Material-UI Grid component

Tags: css, layout, material-ui

I'm trying to implement this layout in Material-UI using the Grid component.

I have highlighted the container border in red to make it clearer where the boundaries are.

- The Add button should be at the right end of the container
- The chips should be aligned on the left and take as much space as possible, horizontally

[image: example 1]

- When chips stack, the Add button should be vertically aligned to the bottom of the container

[image: example 2]

I have managed to implement this using nested Grids, as in this example:

[image: Edit grid nesting example]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Grid, Chip, Box } from '@material-ui/core'

export default function App() {
  const [chips, setChips] = useState(1)

  const addChip = () => setChips(c => c + 1)
  const removeChip = i => setChips(c => c - 1)

  const renderChips = () =>
    Array(chips)
      .fill(null)
      .map((_, i) => (
        <Grid item key={i}>
          <Chip label={`Chip ${i}`} onDelete={() => removeChip(i)} />
        </Grid>
      ))

  return (
    <Box border="1px solid red">
      <Grid container wrap="nowrap" spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
            {renderChips()}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item display="flex" component={Box}>
          <Grid container alignItems="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={addChip}>
                Add
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

I would like to avoid having to nest Grid components more than necessary. More specifically, I would like to use `<Grid item container>` instead of a `<Grid container>` containing a `<Grid item>`, but using that approach I cannot achieve this layout of expanding the chips section on the left and keeping the button on the right, while keeping it aligned to the bottom vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following block

```
<Box border="1px solid red" style={{'postion':'relative'}}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} style={{'padding': '1px 80px 1px 1px'}}>
            {renderChips()}
      </Grid>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={addChip} style={{'position':'relative', 'float': 'right', 'bottom': '35px'}}>
                Add
      </Button>    
</Box>
```

instead of

```
<Box border="1px solid red">
      <Grid container wrap="nowrap" spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
            {renderChips()}
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item display="flex" component={Box}>
          <Grid container alignItems="flex-end">
            <Grid item>
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={addChip}>
                Add
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
```

Comment: Static padding and positioning doesn't quite sound like a good solution.

Comment: Yes. I agree but sometimes it does not hurt, right? For example, in this case, don't you think this is okay. Say,  your button size does not change with window size, so static positioning seems okay to me. I will do the positioning with respect to your parent div (i.e. in this case, with respect to your input div). I will pad your input right with the size of the button length and a little bit more. I will float your button bottom right. Anyway, that is what I did and I can be wrong too.

Comment: Let me clarify the intent of the question then. I'm not looking for an alternative approach to using MUI's Grid, I would know how to implement this using flexbox or other CSS, I would like to understand if there is a better (in other words, less deeply nested) way of achieving what I need using the Grid component

Comment: Apologies. I have misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your grid doesn't align with what you are trying to get:

```
|-----------------------------|-----|
| item1 | item2 | item3 |     |     |  
| item4 | item... | item 20   |     |
| item 21 ...                 | Add |
|-----------------------------|-----|
```

If you split it into two columns - the `Add` button will never align how you want.

Instead - the `Add` should not get it's own column - but should be part of the main block (the same flow of your elements). The only thing that you need to do is to make sure that it's position on the right side, and you can get this with `margin-left: auto`:

```
<Box border="1px solid red">
  <Grid container wrap="nowrap" spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs>
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        {renderChips()}
        <Grid item style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={addChip}>
            Add
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Box>
```

Here is the above implementation based on to your original sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-item-stick-to-right-3xzj2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saying that the Add button will never align like I want, as you can see in the linked example it is aligning properly. Also note that your example doesn't do what I'm trying to achieve because the original example has spacing 1 between the chips and spacing 2 between the chips section and the button. Finally, most of the Grid code in your example is redundant because basically you're not using the Grid. If you read the question more carefully, my intent was to use Grid but avoid the multiple nesting.

Comment: Mostly because in your example if you have two lines - the last item on line 1 will not be right above the "Add" button, so instead of :https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z0Yx.png you will have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTfhn.png Are you looking for that? Regarding the multiple nesting - I guess it's a small issue to resolve.

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with the layout as shown in the question, I don't need the button to be below the chips, I want it in a different column. The question was only about a better way to implement the layout without that amount of nesting.