# What components to layout top level webpage like this

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an existing React Web application that uses a CSS Grid to layout the website, the look is:

```
................... HEADER ......................
NAV MENU |        MAIN AREA       | RIGHT SIDEBAR
..................  FOOTER ......................
```

This existing web app uses CSS gird as shown below:

```
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header header header header header header "
    "menu main main main main main main main main right"
    "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer";
}
```

I'm trying to find a sample react/material-ui application that does something similar.

#### Searching for solution

I found

- The Material-ui.com store has several templates for sale.  https://material-ui.com/store/#populars.  The problem is many of them didn't display (spinner kept spinning).  And most were way more complicated than I want/need.
- A [medium.com article](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/getting-started-with-material-ui-for-react-material-design-for-react-364b2688b555) that referred to this github project [github.com/seeschweiler/react-material-ui](https://github.com/seeschweiler/react-material-ui).  It unfortunately doesn't run.  It attempts to download data from a CDN and gets a 404 when trying to download the data so nothing is displayed.  So I can't see how layout is.  Examining the code showed that it doesn't attempt to have a header/navbar/main area/footer as I'm looking for.
- A SO article that actually might help me out.  I'll look at this more later.  [How to correctly implement this layout using Material-UI Grid component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696478/how-to-correctly-implement-this-layout-using-material-ui-grid-component)
- The [material-ui Grid](https://mui.com/components/grid/) docs which makes me think this might work

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <Item>header</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={2}>
      <Item>nav menu</Item>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={8}>
      <Item>MAIN AREA</Item>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={2}>
      <Item>Right</Item>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    <Item>Footer</Item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I'll give this a try and update the question with a pointer to the sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Grid can work.  See the example solution in [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-dream-3zqpp?file=/src/App.js).
To create this I started with the sample code at https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-frog-30k89, then forked it, and made the `App.js` file change shown below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container items={12}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h1" gutterBottom>
          This is the header
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container items={12}>
        <Grid container items={12}>
          <Grid item xs={2}>Nav Menu</Grid>
          <Grid item xs={8}>Body</Grid>
          <Grid item xs={2}>Right Column</Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container items={12}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          Footer
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

To create this on the desktop  I did the following:

```
curl https://codeload.github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tar.gz/master | tar -xz --strip=2 material-ui-master/examples/create-react-app
cd create-react-app
npm install
npm start
```

See also https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app.

I then changed the `App.js` file as shown above.